# Virtual DocumentRoot configuration for both WWW and non-WWW - WITHOUT redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, virtualhost

I have searched a lot but can't find an answer

When you setup Dynamic Virtual Hosts in Apache, you do something like this:

```
  RewriteEngine On

  # a ServerName derived from a Host: header may be any case at all
  RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

  ## deal with normal documents first:
  # allow Alias /icons/ to work - repeat for other aliases
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/icons/
  # allow CGIs to work
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/
  # do the magic
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /var/www/domains/${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}}/html/$1

  ## and now deal with CGIs - we have to force a MIME type
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgi-bin/
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /var/www/domains/${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}}/cgi-bin/$1 [T=application/x-httpd-cgi]
```

Problem is, you need to create 2 folders:  example.com and www.example.com
(or create one and a symbolic link to it)

What would be a rewrite rule that could avoid having to create those 2 folders? (or the symlink)

The question applies to NGINX as well

Like this question: [Apache vhost with and without 'www'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/258138/apache-vhost-with-and-without-www)  I don't want to use *.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another rewrite rule, that should be before the other one in the config file:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}  ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /www/hosts/${lowercase:%1}/docs/$1
```

What you're doing here is matching the domain name against a regexp. If the domain name starts with "www.", everything after "www." will be stored in the variable %1. In the next line, you're re-using that variable instead of the entire ServerName.

Comment: Do I replace my rule completely with yours or should they work together?

Comment: After doing some more testing, I figured that it is not working. If I try domain2.com then Apache serves the default domain: domain1.com
It correctly works for www.domain2.com though. But it doesn't work when there's no WWW

Comment: Turn on RewriteLog and see what it says when you acess the URL for which the rewrite isn't working.